# How does apps like whatsapp keep track of a users data?

Tags: android, database

In apps like WhatsApp, when a user signs up with his/her mobile number on a certain device (they should be assigned by a certain UID that will be added to the database in order to detect these users).

Let's say a user A signs up with this mobile number (1234) on his device A, then when he/she start a chat the chat thread should be tracked by the database like this:

### users database

```
Users
|
|
|-----UID-1:
      |
      ---phone_number : 1234
      ---name : user A
|
|-----UID-2
      |
       ---phone_number : 4567
       ---name : user B
```

### Chats

```
Chats
|
|
|---UID_1
    |
    |--UID-2
      |......
    |
    |--UID-3
      |.....
```

As you can see user A has 2 chats with UID-2 AND UID-3 (2 threads).

When user A's number expires someone else (user x) with another device (device x) will get user A's number and will use it in his new device.

**My question is:**

If this user x gets his hand on the phone number then when he/she tries to login with this number then he/she should load the threads of user A because he will be assigned with the same UID of user A, because they share the same number.

So how to secure this? Or in other words how WhatsApp and similar popular apps handle this issue?